# underscore method for json retrieval

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I am trying to retrive the values soccer football and not the number 1, 2, 3 but right now i get 1 2 3 can you tell me what i am doing wrong.. 
providing my json and marionette code... 
some problem with this method setupSports...
is there any method in js where we can retrievet the soccer basketball easily

```
_.keys(this.offers)
```

using this i am getting nos 1, 2 but not sure how to get football...how to map it

```
setupSports: function() {
    this.offerCategories = _.map(_.keys(this.offers), function(offer) {
        return {
            title: offer
        };
    });

    this.offerCategories.unshift({ title: SHOW_ALL });

    this.setCurrentSports();
},
```

json

```
{  
   "sports":{  
      "2":{  
         "soccer":[  
            {  
               "soccerDescription":"uiui",
               "basketballDescription":"uiu",
               "footballDescription":"hhh"
            }
         ]
      },
      "1":{  
         "basketball":[  
            {  
               "soccerDescription":"o",
               "basketballDescription":"i",
               "footballDescription":"i"
            }
         ]
      },
      "6":{  
         "football":[  
            {  
               "soccerDescription":"y",
               "basketballDescription":"h",
               "footballDescription":"ii"
            },
            {  
               "soccerDescription":"o",
               "basketballDescription":"o",
               "footballDescription":"kk"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible 'this' is out of scope? Try

```
var that = this;
this.offerCategories = _.map(_.keys(this.offers), function(offer) {
    return {
        title: _.keys(that.offers[offer])[0]
    };
});
```

Comment: just playing around with it, seems to likely be the case.  otherwise, @epascarello seems to have been spot on.

Comment: thanks for your reply its working but i am getting undefined at another place...at this place this.currentOffers = this.offers; in this method setCurrentSports http://jsfiddle.net/bb094yto/1/

Comment: please accept and upvote any answers that helped you solve your original problem, ill take a look at this one now.

Comment: thanks. i upvoted epascarello for the help.  still checking the second undefined problem out.

Comment: since i dont have the rest of the code to actually run it, this second problem is a bit trickier, but my inclination is that the offersKey paramater of the setCurrentSports method is being set to a value that's not in this.offers. if offersKey wasn't being set, it would return an array of all offers correctly, so the problem is likely in the line this.offers=this.offers[offersKey].  set a breakpoint on the line with this.currentOffers = this.offers in debugger, and when it hits that breakpoint, check in console what is the value of offersKey

Comment: for offersKey it shows undefined...any problem with my array iteration

Comment: if offersKey is undefined, then its setting this.offers equal to _.chain(this.offers).values().flatten().value(), which works, as long as this.offers is defined.  So now my thinking is that this.offers is undefined before this line.  set a breakpoint again on the line  this.offers = _.chain(this.offers).values().flatten().value(); and see what the value of this.offers is

Answer (score 1):

Well you would need to loop through the keys of the second object.

```
this.offerCategories = _.map(_.keys(this.offers), function(offer) {
    return {
        title: _.keys(this.offers[offer])[0]
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...but i am getting this erro Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offers' of undefined ...used your return statement...providing my code in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bb094yto/

Comment: thanks for your reply its working but i am getting undefined at another place...at this place this.currentOffers = this.offers; in this method setCurrentSports http://jsfiddle.net/bb094yto/1/

Answer (score 0):

When targeting data in a JSON object, you would need to target the specific path to the data that you want. So say this was in JS, and you wanted to console.log these 3 things. You would do something like

```
var soccer = sports[0].2;
var basketball = sports[0].1;
var football = sports[0].6;
```

console.log(soccer + basketball + football);

Comment: then why its noit working return {
        title: _.keys(this.offers[offer])[0]
    };